# Multiple loops to Recursive method c#

Tags: c#, recursion, nested

I have an object with multiple nested objects in it. The classes:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Element> SubElement { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ElementConfig ElementConfig { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Element ParentElement { get; set; }

}
public class SubElement
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ElementConfig {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string IconName { get; set; }
}
```

The base is that an `Element` can have multiple `SubElements` with their own `ElementConfig`. I want to populate the `ElementConfig` for each `Element`, doing it like this:

```
    private void Recursion(Element element)
    {
        //TODO: use recursion ??
        foreach (Element item in element.SubElement)
        {
            item.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.Key);
            item.ParentElement = element;

            foreach (Element x in item.SubElement)
            {
                x.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Key == x.Key);
                x.ParentElement = item;

                foreach (Element y in x.SubElement)
                {
                    y.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Key == y.Key);
                    y.ParentElement = x;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

This is working, but I want to use a Recursive method to do this. Is this possible?

**EDIT**
From the suggestion from @johnathan Barclay I use following approach:

```
element.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == element.Key);

        foreach (var item in element.SubElement)
        {
            item.ParentElement = element;
            Recursion(item); 
        }
```

This helps getting the `ElementConfig` for each first `SubElement`. What happens now is that the following SubElements are not filled.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  In your `Recursion` method, what happens when you call `Recursion(item)` in your loop?

Comment: As a side note for later: Depending on how deep your recursion will be, consider using a ```Stack<Element>``` instead of recursively calling ```Recursion```.

Comment: @David When i call `Recursion(item)` in my first loop, I see that the first `SubElement` is filled, but not the next items. I never used Recursion so far.

Comment: Does `ElementConfig` need to be set for the root element?

Comment: Yes, this is done just before the call. `Element root = navigationStructureConfig.Root.Element;
            root.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == root.Key);`

Comment: @Yens: If you've made an attempt to use recursion, show that attempt in the question and describe in what way it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ElementConfig` also needs to be set for the root element:

```
private void Recursion(Element element)
{
    element.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == element.Key);
    
    foreach (var item in element.SubElement)
    {
        item.ParentElement = element;    
        Recursion(item); // Recurse here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Before using the nested loops, i tried a similar approach. The good thing is that this fills up the first SubElement. But somehow, it skips the next SubElements. So SubElement[0] is always filled, SubElement[1] is not.

Comment: Not sure how that's possible unless an exception is being thrown?

Comment: There is no Exception thrown. See the last Edit for a visual representation, if that helps..

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code, where you call the `Recursion` method?

Comment: I simply get the Root and call the Recursion method: `Element root = navigationStructureConfig.Root.Element; Recursion(root);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an generic iterative solution:

```
public void PupulateConfigAndParent(Element element){
    foreach(var (item, parent) in DepthFirstWithParent(element, e => e.SubElement)){
        item.ElementConfig = navigationStructureConfig.ElementConfigs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.Key);
        item.ParentElement = parent;
    }
}

    public static IEnumerable<(T Node, T Parent)> DepthFirstWithParent<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<(T Node, T Parent)>();
        stack.Push((self, self));
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;
            foreach (var child in selector(current.Node))
            {
                stack.Push((child, current.Node ));
            }
        }
    }
```

An advantage of this is the ability to reuse the generic method for any kind of tree like structure. Note that the root node will have itself as the parent.